# CMS для блога

Tags: php, cms, opensource

Нужна очень CMS для блога с минимальным функционалом - написание новостей, вывод, тэги.
Желательно OpenSource

Comment: Для "минимала" пишите сами - PHP, ASP.NET (хостинг дороже) - как говориться: "карты Вам в руки". Но лучше не выдумывайте велосипед (тоже спорный вопрос), возьмите на изучение существующие системы, а далее переделайте их под ваши запросы.

Answer (score 7):

Я бы порекомендовал [wordpress](http://ru.wordpress.org/):

1. В принципе, очень просто, установка в несколько кликов.
2. Куча шаблонов.
3. Еще больше модулей, если вдруг решите развивать проект.
4. Возможность протестировать на бесплатном хостинге с доменом третьего уровня.
5. Огромное сообщество.

Comment: Конечно Wordpress, тут и говорить не о чем, движка для блогов удобнее, пока не видел.

Answer (score 2):

Однозначно wordpress.
Он просто заточен под блог уже изначально.
Можно еще TYPO 3 использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну тот же самый Друпал подойдет для создания блога. Вот статья о нём: https://coba.tools/drupal, почитайте, там как раз написано, что для блогов подходит, да и набор возможностей отличный.